# html/css floating image right of text

Tags: html, css, floating

I am attempting to float an image to the right of some text currently wrapped in the P tag inside a parent div. using float: right for the image takes it all the way to the right but under the text.

I would like to see them aligned side by side, please check screenshot here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3STRGf0b16iNWhMVDBETEpaczQ/view?usp=drivesdk

My css

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'open sans';
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    max-width: 550px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: .9em;
    line-height: 1.8em;
}

.why-nexishost {
    width: 980px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 70px auto 0 auto;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.quality-badge {
    float: right;
}
```

My html

```
<head>
    <title>NexisHost</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
            <div class="header-content">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter-icon.png" class="twitter-icon" alt="Twitter icon"></a>
                <ul>
                    <li>Support 513.571.7809</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Account Manager</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="navigation">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Site Logo">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Domains</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Signup</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="home-banner"></div>
            <div class="why-nexishost">
                    <h1>Quality is our #1 priority</h1>
                    <p>A domain name, your address on the Internet, says a lot about who you are and what you do. New domain endings like .guru and .photography can help you find a meaningful address that stands out on the web. Every domain includes website forwarding, email forwarding (help@your_company), simple management tools and other helpful features.</p><img src="images/premium_quality-01-256.png" class="quality-badge" alt="Quality Guarantee badge">
            </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this:

```
p{
  display: inline-block;
}

.quality-badge{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

You can also do this by floating left as another person suggested, but inline-blocks will put things in a line.

You can check [this site](http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html) out for more info.

I'm not sure what is considered better-practice, I think inline-blocks are just the newer way of doing things although old versions of some browsers may not support it. [This site shows which don't.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=inline-block)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to float your `<p>` left, not your image right.

```
p {
    float: left;
    ...
}

.quality-badge {
    //float: right;
}
```

Comment: Both of your suggestions worked. The question now is which is the best practice for doing what I'm trying to accomplish ? :P

Comment: Not a question of best practices really. This code just does what you describe. Just a matter of visualizing how the blocks fit together with the relevant CSS properties applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this with your current css:

```
<div class="why-nexishost">
    <img src="images/premium_quality-01-256.png" class="quality-badge" alt="Quality Guarantee badge">
    <h1>Quality is our #1 priority</h1>
    <p>A domain name, your address on the Internet, says a lot about who you are and what you do. New domain endings like .guru and .photography can help you find a meaningful address that stands out on the web. Every domain includes website forwarding, email forwarding (help@your_company), simple management tools and other helpful features.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to keep `float:right` applied to your image.  This will make your image float to the right and HTML elements that *come after it* in the same container will wrap around it.  However, you'll need to move your `img` tag up so it comes before the text you want to wrap.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="myImage.png" class="myImage" alt="Alt Text" />
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Paragraph text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myImage {
    float:left;
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3zt4g6n/) using your code for a demonstration.

If you want the container to expand to the size of the floating image (by default if the image is bigger than the container it overflows out) you can add the following CSS to your container class:

```
.container { overflow: auto; }
```

As an additional note, your `img` tags aren't closed (you have `<img src="source" >` rather than `<img src="source" />` which will probably cause rendering errors in at least some browsers.

You can learn more about `float` and `clear` in CSS [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp).